# How to display element from string table

Tags: c, string

I read char from UART and want to make table of array. When I made 1 dimensional array (Commented code) everything is okay but with 2 doesn't. 

 message is 'HELLO'

```
int i=0, j=0;
char ch;    
char stringArray[50][50] ={"",""};   //stringArray[50]="";

while(1){
    ch  = readCharUART();

        if(ch!=13)
        {
            if (ch == 10)
            {
                dispChar(179);
                j++;                    
            }
            else{   
                dispChar(ch);
                stringArray[i][j] = ch;  //stringArray[i]
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dispString(stringArray[0]);     //here no output
           //dispString(stringArray); // 'HELLO'
    }}
```

What is wrong with it? How to fix it?

******EDIT***************
When 1d table is defined, output is correct.
When 2d table is defined, there is **no output** screen is clear

Comment: Please show us what's inside your functions.

Comment: I think maybe you want to exchange `i` and `j` at the increment lines. Increment `i` when `ch == 10` otherwise increment `j`.

Comment: Are you getting any error or it works but the output is not as expected??

Comment: I swap i with j, but still doesn't work.
I do not have any output.

Comment: what is the definition of `dispString(stringArray[0])`?

Comment: dispString displays string e.g. dispString("Hello"); -> Hello on LCD display

Comment: Define "it's not OK".

Comment: The question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char stringArray[50][50] ={"",""};  //wrong

char stringArray[50][50] ={"","", "", ...}; //50 times
```